# How to calculate a price from a database column

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to calculate the overall price from a database column called "price". The idea is that users place an order, which is recorded in the `orders` table. An admin then comes along and can view the total profit made on *all* the orders.

I have no idea how to do this. I *think* I need to put it into a `for ... loop` and add the results on top of each other. But I am not sure where to start. (I have been using ColdFusion for maybe 2 days now, so any and all help is appreciated.).

**EDIT** - Further info,
I am using SQL server 2008 with sqlsrv and ColdFusion 9. After double checking the database its not price it's "orderValue".

**EDIT** - More further info, Thanks for all the help and what not, about the total vat, etc that i mentioned in another comment, i want to do this myself, this is a starting point and it is enough to tick the last requirements box of this shopping site for uni, however i want to progress it after ive handed it in tomorrow (deadline) and i was more stating my further plans than asking for help, again thank you guys for all the help really a great community here.

Comment: Though it should not make a difference in this particular case, it is always good to include your database type and version with db questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to do this in SQL, not ColdFusion:

```
<cfquery name="totalSalesQuery">
    SELECT SUM(price) AS totalSales
    FROM orders
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>#totalSalesQuery.totalSales#</cfoutput>
```

**Also...**

You won't be able to calculate profit from the price column in the orders table. You'd need to have a way of subtracting out the cost of each order to determine profit. So I assume you're actually looking for total sales.

If you want to format the result as US dollars, you can wrap your output in a formatting function:

```
<cfoutput>#dollarFormat(totalSalesQuery.totalSales)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, yeah im looking for profit, but before i get there show how much money total has been made, then calc the VAT and non VAT price from the total, then show the profit

Comment: you're going to need to post your database structure

Comment: @zoro724 - Then you need to a) post a [ddl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) of the table(s) and columns involved b) describe how those columns are used to calculate the "profit" and c) a data sample (showing the expected results) would not hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

It's may be best to just do this in SQL, depending upon your other code. For instance if you're using T-SQL (MS SQL) then use the following statement:

```
<cfquery name="qProfit">
    SELECT SUM(price) AS profit
    FROM orders
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
Profit: #qProfit.profit#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: The sum of the price is not the profit.  The sum of the price sold minus the sum of the purchase price is the profit.

Comment: @DanBracuk - The OP did not mention anything other than "price" until much later. In fact he still has not clarified exactly how he is defining "profit" ... Chris' answer was valid given the limited information available at the time.

Answer (score 0):

As other users have pointed out running a SQL query is best, but in case you can't create a new SQL statement here is how you you can loop over your existing query and add the values to a variable.

```
--Sample query
<cfquery name="getOrders">
SELECT orderid, price
FROM orders
</cfquery>

<cfset totalprice = 0>
<cfloop query="getOrders">
  <cfset totalprice+=getOrders.price>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have already chosen an answer, and if this is the only column you need to get the sum of, it's the way I'd do it as well. If you however need to output a bunch of other things, and also want to sum a few columns without too many queries running, this is a pretty nifty way to do it that isn't very well known:

```
<cfset totalInvoiced=arraySum(selectQueryName["columnname"]) />
```

Or to fancify output (make sure it returns number format with 2 decimals for example):

```
<cfset totalInvoiced=numberFormat(arraySum(selectQueryName["columnname"]),".00") />
```